# Plastic with fluid inside

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor

Can anyone help with a node setup for the plastic and the fluid inside it?

This is my reference picture:

[image]

I have already modelled some of the containers and the liquid inside, but I wanted to create a more photorealistic render.

Here is what I have so far:

[image]

As you can see, the material is either too transparent (and it looks glassy) or too opaque (and you can't see the fluid inside). Any help is appreciated.

Here's my .blend file: [image]

EDIT: Here's my render after playing with Michael Ben David's setup:

[image]

Still figuring things out, but it already looks pretty good!

Comment: Can you please attach your .blend file by uploading it with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? It seems to me, that the walls of the container may be a little bit thick and there is not enough lighting + the container is too reflective

Comment: Thank you! I remodelled the fluid so the walls look thinner and it already looks better. I'll upload the .blend because I still can't get the materials to look right. Still, thank you for answering!

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5887/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok try it myself with a complex node setup based in this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTlKB.png so here is the blender file that i did some necessary changes like remove (tho all objects arent removed all duplicated vertices just a few that i saw so you must remove them) duplicated vertices, and flip normals and reduce policycount of some objects that doesnt need too much polygons (like the plane and rock detail that you made), and also fixed smoothing a bit, and i added solididy modifier to the garrafa that i tested there and also the grass (the grass needed it because shading errors). also delete the modifiers that you arent using like surfsub modifier in las garrafas que hiciste pero left the solidify modifier. also copy the material for the another garrafa.and Happy blending!! [image] [image]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for answering! I'm still a noob so I've got a lot to fix! Thank you for the tips, I will definitely look into this and try my way. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @GustavoDias De nada Amigo!! dale en el boton verde que esta a lado del post

Answer (score 4):

I played around a little bit and came up with the following setting for the plastic and the fluid, I think it comes close to the real anti-frost fluid/container and by changing the settings slightly you should get what you want. I would also make the walls thinner, in the corners you can see that there is still quite a lot of plastic

[image]

Comment: Quite hard try.!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will play around with your setup, this looks really good! Thank you for your time and happy blending!